# How to use cordova/phonegap in my website?

Tags: web, phonegap-build, phonegap, cordova-3, phonegap-cli

I have a site, and i need to use `cordova/phonegap` in my site. because some features are available in `cordova/phonegap`. 
so i need to use that features in my site using `cordova`(**I don't want to convert my site into app**) i just use `cordova` for 
some benifits.

any idea? Thanks in advance